# How to handle requests after Elastic load balancer (AWS) without Server name

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have web app (Elastic load balancer (ELB), one EC2 instance, docker containers (ecs): nginx + golang). For example, there are 2 points - **first.example.com** and **second.example.com**. As I understand, Elastic load balancer (ELB) not support Server Name. How can I switch requests between different app endpoints without server name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ELB doesn't work with "server names" or DNS names which is what I think you need. An ELB has it's own DNS name that you can hook up your own domain eg. **first.example.com** using a CNAME or ALIAS (Route53) record. See the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html#dns-associate-custom-elb) for clarification.

An ELB serves the nodes that are individually associated to it and/or the nodes in any AutoScaling groups associated with if.

If you need to serve 2 different endpoints and you want to use an ELB, you're going to need 2 ELBs.